# How do I define a constructor for all subclasses

Tags: java, oop

I'm making a chess game and each Piece has a subclass - King, Queen, Rook etc

Each Piece has a playerId attribute which I want to set like this:

```
public abstract class Piece {

    private int playerId;

    public Piece(int playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }
}
```

But this only works if I instantiate Piece directly (which I can't anyway, because it's abstract). Is there a way to make this constructor apply to ALL subclasses, without having to manually implement it in each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way. In each of the descendants write something like this:

```
public Rook(int playerId) {
    super(playerId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, your IDE can do this for you.  When you extend Piece it should offer to add all the constructors you need.  It still needs to be done, but avoids having to do it manually.

Perhaps you can avoid sub-classing Piece by making seperating its behaviour from the Pieces.

```
enum PieceType {
  KING, QUEEN, ROOK;
}

public class Piece {
  private final PieceType pieceType;
  private final String playerId;
  public Piece ... // one constructor for all.
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but each piece has other attributes I need to manage. I'll just write the constructors in every class :P

Comment: @matt, if you are using an IDE, you really shouldn't need to. Can you give examples of other attributes you need to manage? You can may find enum's can do alot more than you expect.

Comment: The second suggestion would make for a very un-OO design. I would rather have polymorphic methods like piece.getValidMoves() than a whole lot of switch statements.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about static factory methods.

```
public abstract class Piece
{
  private int playerId;

  public int getPlayerId()
  {
    return playerId;
  }

  public int setPlayerId(int playerId)
  {
    this.playerId = playerId;
  }
}

public class King extends Piece
{
  //King specific stuff in here
}

public class ChessFactory
{
  public static King newKing(int id)
  {
    King king = new King();
    king.setId(id);
    return king;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (The way I usually do this) is to have a **protected** piece constructor

```
public abstract class Piece {

    private int playerId;

    protected Piece(int playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }
}
```

and for every subpiece, e.g. Rook

```
public class Rook extends Piece {

    public Rook(int playerId) {
        super(playerId);
    }
}
```

That way, the constructor for `Piece` is indeed to everyone except its descendants.